# Different row height for items in an ObservableCollection bound to an ItemsControl, depending on the datatype

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, itemscontrol, itemspaneltemplate

Does anyone know if it's possible to differ the height of each item in a ItemsControl depending on the DataType of the item in question?

Let's say I have an ObservableCollection of objects, roughly like this:

```
SomeItemToDraw
SomeItemToDraw
SomeItemToDraw
Divider
SomeItemToDraw
SomeItemToDraw
Divider
SomeItemToDraw
```

I've bound this to an ItemsControl, with different datatemplates for each type:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Myitems}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <UniformGrid Columns="1" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsControl.Resources>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type example:SomeItemToDraw>
      <!-- A big ascii owl -->
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type example:Divider>
      <!-- A single line -->
    </DataTemplate>

</ItemsControl.Resources>
```

Obviously in the above, each item is given equal space. So a single line is given the same space as a massive ascii owl.

Is it possible, without having a fixed collection (say it's random every time), to ensure that we still fill the parent container *and* ensure that the 'Divider' datatypes only get a 1px height, whilst the ascii owls get an equal share of the rest each?

Or is this not possible? In which case are we looking at a DataGrid where every bit of styling is set to be completely invisible?

Comment: Do not use a **Uniform**Grid as ItemsPanel.

Comment: But then, what else is there to use? A StackPanel won't allow the behavioir I'm looking for (you can't expand to fix in a StackPanel?) and defining a grid isn't going to work as we don't know the total rows or where the dividers will be.

Comment: "expand to fix" means horizontal stretching? That's well possible with a StackPanel and happens by default when you do not set the ItemsPanel at all and put the ItemsControl into e.g. a Grid.

Comment: Expand to fill, sorry. As in, I have a vertical space my ItemsControl fills. If I don't specify an ItemsPanel we only take up the space the collection fills, leaving lots of white space at the bottom. I want the Divider items to take up only what they need, and SomeItemToDraw to be given an even division of the rest.

Comment: That's quite difficult I guess. You may probably write a custom Panel with an attached property that controls whether a child element is proportionally stretched or not. Such a property would have to set in an ItemContainerStyle depending on the type of the data item.

Comment: Yeah, it's such a simple UI thing for a user, but is proving to be a bit of a pain to get it looking right for them.

I'll start looking at a custom panel.